# Unknown character set utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm developing my PHP apps on XAMMP on a usb stick, the character set is utf8_unicode_ci, when I exported the db and imported the SQL into my live server at OVH, it gave me this error:

## 1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

My XAMMP dev server DB version:

```
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
```

My OVH live server version:

```
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.1.73 - Source distribution
```

No how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use my sql server 5.5.3 or newer, or replace all 'utf8mb4' to 'utf8' in your DB dump